# Copy Paste in 2 Different Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css

My Code works for 1 canvas. But **I need this implementation to work for 2 of canvas**.

So I tried

```
  var SIGNATURE_2 = new CLIPBOARD_CLASS("signatureCanvas2", true);
```

The problem is that this always pastes the image in the first canvas, I just need to press Ctrl+V. 
**How do I paste ONLY when the canvas is focused or hovered?**

```js
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Copy paste Image to Canvas
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    var SIGNATURE = new CLIPBOARD_CLASS("signatureCanvas", true);
    var SIGNATURE_2 = new CLIPBOARD_CLASS("signatureCanvas2", true);

    /**
     * image pasting into canvas
     * 
     * @param {string} canvas_id - canvas id
     * @param {boolean} autoresize - if canvas will be resized
     */
    function CLIPBOARD_CLASS(canvas_id, autoresize) {
        var _self = this;
        var canvas = document.getElementById(canvas_id);
        var ctx = document.getElementById(canvas_id).getContext("2d");
        var ctrl_pressed = false;
        var command_pressed = false;
        var paste_event_support;
        var pasteCatcher;

        //handlers
        document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            _self.on_keyboard_action(e);
        }, false); //firefox fix
        document.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
            _self.on_keyboardup_action(e);
        }, false); //firefox fix
        document.addEventListener('paste', function (e) {
            _self.paste_auto(e);
        }, false); //official paste handler

        //constructor - we ignore security checks here
        this.init = function () {
            pasteCatcher = document.createElement("div");
            pasteCatcher.setAttribute("id", "paste_ff");
            pasteCatcher.setAttribute("contenteditable", "");
            pasteCatcher.style.cssText = 'opacity:0;position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;width:10px;margin-left:-20px;';
            document.body.appendChild(pasteCatcher);

            // create an observer instance
            var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
                mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
                    if (paste_event_support === true || ctrl_pressed == false || mutation.type != 'childList'){
                        //we already got data in paste_auto()
                        return true;
                    }

                    //if paste handle failed - capture pasted object manually
                    if(mutation.addedNodes.length == 1) {
                        if (mutation.addedNodes[0].src != undefined) {
                            //image
                            _self.paste_createImage(mutation.addedNodes[0].src);
                        }
                        //register cleanup after some time.
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            pasteCatcher.innerHTML = '';
                        }, 20);
                    }
                });
            });
            var target = document.getElementById('paste_ff');
            var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };
            observer.observe(target, config);
        }();
        //default paste action
        this.paste_auto = function (e) {
            paste_event_support = false;
            if(pasteCatcher != undefined){
                pasteCatcher.innerHTML = '';
            }
            if (e.clipboardData) {
                var items = e.clipboardData.items;
                if (items) {
                    paste_event_support = true;
                    //access data directly
                    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                        if (items[i].type.indexOf("image") !== -1) {
                            //image
                            var blob = items[i].getAsFile();
                            var URLObj = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                            var source = URLObj.createObjectURL(blob);
                            this.paste_createImage(source);
                        }
                    }
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
                else {
                    //wait for DOMSubtreeModified event              
                }
            }
        };
        //on keyboard press
        this.on_keyboard_action = function (event) {
            var k = event.keyCode;
            //ctrl
            if (k == 17 || event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey) {
                if (ctrl_pressed == false)
                    ctrl_pressed = true;
            }
            //v
            if (k == 86) {
                if (document.activeElement != undefined && document.activeElement.type == 'text') {
                    //let user paste into some input
                    return false;
                }

                if (ctrl_pressed == true && pasteCatcher != undefined){
                    pasteCatcher.focus();
                }
            }
        };
        //on kaybord release
        this.on_keyboardup_action = function (event) {
            //ctrl
            if (event.ctrlKey == false && ctrl_pressed == true) {
                ctrl_pressed = false;
            }
            //command
            else if(event.metaKey == false && command_pressed == true){
                command_pressed = false;
                ctrl_pressed = false;
            }
        };
        //draw pasted image to canvas
        this.paste_createImage = function (source) {
            var pastedImage = new Image();
            pastedImage.onload = function () {
                if(autoresize == true){
                    //resize
                    canvas.width = pastedImage.width;
                    canvas.height = pastedImage.height;
                }
                else{
                    //clear canvas
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                }
                ctx.drawImage(pastedImage, 0, 0);
            };
            pastedImage.src = source;
        };
    }
```

```css
.signatureCanvas {
    border:1px solid #027C8C;
    width: 100%;
    max-height:200px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="signatureCanvas" class="signatureCanvas"></canvas>
 
  <canvas id="signatureCanvas2" class="signatureCanvas"></canvas>
```

**PS: Please just open snipping tool on windows and copy paste an image to test**

Answer (score 0):

Detect if mouse is over canvas, and store it in a variable.

```
var over_canvas=false;
document.getElementById("signatureCanvas").addEventListener("mouseover", function (i) {
    over_canvas=true;
});
document.getElementById("signatureCanvas").addEventListener("mouseout", function (i) {
    over_canvas=false;
});
```

When pasting, check if mouse is over canvas by changing your paste function to:

```
document.addEventListener('paste', function (e) {
    if (over_canvas){
    _self.paste_auto(e);
    }
}, false);
```